# How to sort returned sql result by id that appears the most time in that result

Tags: php, mysql, list, sorting

I have table `offer_cpv` that is connecting two others "`offer`" and "`cpv`". You can see fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02020/1

`offer_cpv` has two columns that are important for us: `offer_id` and `cpv_id`.

My starting query looks like this: `SELECT cpv_id FROM offer_cpv WHERE offer_id IN (1,2,3,4) LIMIT 10`

As you can see I need to return all `cpv_id` based on the array of `offer_id` ( I pass that to `WHERE IN (offer_id)`.

I will get this result:

```
cpv_id
1010
1020
1030
2010
4030
4060
1010
2010
1010
1020
```

As you can see some cpv_id are repeating because several offers may have same cpv_id linked to them. I need to get list of "most popular" cpv_id, I mean if some id is repeating the most time I need it to be on top of list. For example, this would be desired output:

```
cpv_id
1010
1020
2010
1030
4030
4060
```

As you can see 1010 is repeating 3 times so I want it on top of returned result. Then comes 1020 and 2010 since they are repeating 2 times, an then come others until limit of 10 is reached.

Is this possible to do somehow with MYSQL and PHP ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `count(*)` and `group by`

```
SELECT cpv_id,count(*) as tot FROM offer_cpv 
WHERE offer_id IN (1,2,3,4) 
group by cpv_id
order by tot desc
LIMIT 10
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02020/3

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct to get only unique values. Here is your query:

```
SELECT
    distinct cpv_id
FROM
    offer_cpv
WHERE
    offer_id IN (1,2,3,4)
LIMIT 10
```